# Microsoft Graph API - new delegated permission removing application permissions

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the v1 Azure AD auth URLs (`/common/oauth2/authorize`) for a multi-tenant app that requires `admin_consent`.

I've attempted to add a new scope `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`. It is the first 'delegated' permission I'm requesting when all my other scopes are 'application' level permissions.

When I added that new delegated scope and prompted the admin to re-consent, the other scopes disappeared from the returned `AccessToken` and the responses `scope` parameter. Only `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` is present in the `access_token` `scp` field.

**Is there any reason this behavior would occur?** I'm positive that we are promoting for `admin_consent` and that an admin is the one consenting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scopes specified in the `scp` will depend on which OAUTH flow you used to obtain the token. You cannot have a single `access_token` with both Delegated *and* Application scopes.

- Application scopes are applied when using the Client Credentials flow (`client_credentials`).
- Delegated scopes are applied when using either Authorization Code or Implicit flows (`authorization_code` or `implicit`).

Update: I've written a more in-depth post about this topic that might help folks facing similar issues: [Application vs Delegated Scopes](https://massivescale.com/application-vs-delegated-scopes/).

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. 

Up until now we've used the `authorization_code` flow to retrieve our access tokens with application level permissions without issue. 

The problem seems to stem from us wanting the `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permission in order to add directory roles. Which according to documentation can only be done using this delegated scope. Is it possible to get application and delegated permission for one app or must you choose which path to go down?

Comment: You can have both kinds of permissions. You can get another access token with client credentials and that will definitely contain the roles that your app has from app permissions.

Comment: There is no reason why not but since you require Delegated you likely don't need Application scopes at all. App scopes are generally more restrictive than an Administrator using Deleagted scopes. App scopes should generally be limited to headless scenarios where you have no other options available.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT we managed to consolidate all of our applications scopes into 2 delegated scopes, `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` and the `Mail.Send` delegated permission.

Again though the token is only coming back with the `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` scope. The only difference between the scopes is that `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` needs admin consent which we are always prompting for.

Comment: There are two concent types: 1) Admin Consent which consents to Users from their tenant authorizing a set of scopes from a given App Id. 2) User Consent which consents to a set of scopes from a given App Id. Normally new scopes will request consent once the existing tokens have expired. You can however force user's to re-consent to new scopes right away from adding `prompt=consent` to your authorization URL.

Comment: To be clear we did force the admin to reaccept scopes using `prompt=admin_consent` before we evaluated the scopes contained in the token. Is the assumption that a `admin_consent` would only consent scopes that require a admin?

Comment: `admin_consent` only consents to normal users consenting to your app, it doesn't replace user `consent`. Think of `admin_consent` as giving permission for normal users to `consent` to your scopes.